# @Resource annotation not working properly with JBoss5.0.1

Tags: java, spring, jboss5.x, java-ee-5

I'm tring to deploy my app in JBoss 5.0.1. Some of my beans in this app are using `@Resource` annotations. If i understood the problem, my guess is JBoss is tring to process this annotation before spring-core. And i noticed that "Mapped-name" is mandatory for JBoss implementation of `@Resource` annotation.

```
15:53:04,037 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/***] startup failed due to previous errors
java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for com.***.***.**ServiceImpl/XXprocess
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs(WebResourceHandler.java:287)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:325)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:550)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebCtxLoader.start(WebCtxLoader.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4272)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAct
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.ja
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1440)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1158)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1179)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1211)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1099)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
```

Comment: I am facing same problem. You solved it? any other answer?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this mapped-name exception problem.  What fixed it for me was using an older version of the Web Application schema.

I changed my web.xml from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
...
</web-app>
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem too. I'm using JBoss 5.1.0-GA

On my case the problem was that **javaee-api-5.jar** library was being packaged into my application (ear).
This library was in conflict with Jboss libs.

Just remove javaee-api-5.jar (or similiar one) from your application.

Using maven, you can add an exclusion:

```
<exclusion>
        <groupId>javaee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```