# JBoss - Autowiring list - @Resource, @Inject throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, jboss, autowired

Env - JBoss 5.1, Spring 3.1.2, jdk 1.5

I am trying to autowire a list. As per the discussion here [Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception), @Resource doesn't work with JBoss.

```
<util:list id="reportTypes">
  <value>PDF</value>
  <value>CSV</value>
  <value>XML</value>
</util:list>

@Inject
private List<String> reportTypes;
```

I also tried using @Inject, but I get the same exception. What am I missing ?

I am using the JSR 330, com.springsource.javax.inject-0.9.0.PFD.jar file for @Inject as mentioned here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78737-JSR-330-Inject-Spring-3-0

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency 
[collection of java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

**EDIT** using

```
@Resource(name = "reportTypes")
private List<String> reportTypes;
```

throws

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for reportTypes of deployment app.war 
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXmlResourceEnvRefs(WebResourceHandler.java:287)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.injection.WebResourceHandler.loadXml(WebResourceHandler.java:325)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processMetadata(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:550)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebCtxLoader.start(WebCtxLoader.java:158)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `@Resource` doesn't work?

Comment: Using @Resource,     I get java.lang.RuntimeException: mapped-name is required for ... deployment....<weapp>.war. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105155/jboss-5-1-spring-resource-annotation-not-working

Comment: The following should work just fine:

   @Resource(name="reportTypes")
   private List<String> reportTypes;

Comment: I've edited my problem description and added the exception for using @Resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've battled with this problem a few times myself. I don't have an exact answer to your question, other than the fact that I've moved to using @Inject @Named pairs. That seems to work most of the time.

The reason @Resource doesn't work, to my knowledge, is not the fault of jboss itself, but the fault of the version of tomcat bundled by jboss.